# WinRT XAML Toolkit - Numeric Up Down - Set size of change

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I want to set size of change after use one from two buttons connected with NumericUpDown control.

I have something like this:

```
<toolkit:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="1" Minimum="2"  ValueFormat="F0" Value="4" LargeChange="1" Maximum="10"/>
```

In WPF's NumericUpDown is property "*increment*", but I this I can't find. I think that it can be *LargeChange*, but it not working for me. I want to set increment = 1.

In example increment is 0,1

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set the SmallChange to 1. This will result in the change of 1 every time you increment the value.

```
<toolkit:NumericUpDown ValueFormat="F0" Value="4" SmallChange="1" Maximum="10" />
```